# Swift Assign object to function argument inside function

Tags: swift, uikit

I would like to simplifie creation of complex UIView structures by passing outlet variables to be set by receiving views. I already have this

```
class ExampleController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private(set) var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet private(set) var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private(set) var spacer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private(set) var messageLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIStackView(outlet: { stackView = $0 }, arrangedSubviews: [
            UILabel().outlet { titleLabel = $0 },
            UIView().outlet { spacer = $0 },
            UILabel().outlet { messageLabel = $0 },
        ])
    }
}

extension UIView {
    @objc func outlet(_ outlet: (UIView) -> Void) -> UIView {
        outlet(self)
        return self
    }
}

extension UIStackView {

    @discardableResult
    convenience init(outlet: (UIStackView) -> Void, arrangedSubviews: [UIView]) {
        self.init()
        outlet(self)
        arrangedSubviews.forEach { addArrangedSubview($0) }
    }
}

extension UILabel {

    override func outlet(_ outlet: (UILabel) -> Void) -> UILabel {
        outlet(self)
        return self
    }
}
```

I am looking for a solution to simplifie closures responsable for outlet assignments.
Instead writing

```
UILabel().outlet { titleLabel = $0 }
```

It would be great to write

```
UILabel().outlet(titleLabel)
// or
UILabel().outlet { titleLabel }
```

Any ideas how to do it ?

**--- Update**

KeyPath can be a solution. Syntax becomes quite ok.

```
extension UILabel {

    func outlet<T: NSObject>(object: T, _ outletKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, UILabel?>) -> UILabel {
        object[keyPath: outletKeyPath] = self
        return self
    }

}
    
    UILabel().outlet(object: self, \.titleLabel)
```

Inout is the solution:

```
extension UILabel {

    func outlet(_ outlet: inout UILabel?) -> UILabel {
        outlet = self
        return self
    }
    
}

UILabel().outlet(&titleLabel)
```

Comment: are you creating the label in your storyboard/nib file? if so, couldn't you ctrl+drag the label to your outlet?

Comment: There is no storyboards or xibs. Views are created in code. I keep @IBOutlets for commenting reasons.

Comment: "I keep @IBOutlets for commenting reasons." — this is very confusing, could you please elaborate?

Comment: i usually just do `private let titleLabel = UILabel()` or create it within a closure that autoexecutes (`private let titleLabel = { /* initialize label, set properties */ }()`). I'd recommend just using comments to actually comment your code. Tip:  if you do `// MARK: - UI Properties` you'll be able to easily navigate through xcode